# Reset Logic Pro X installation

Tags: macos, logic

I was installing Logic Pro X. The installer had to download 2.0GB. As I have slow internet connection, I was cancelling the download and resuming it without problems the last couple of days.

Today, the download was at 1.4GB. After cancelling it and trying to resume later, the installer won't open. I went to `Activity Monitor` and killed the `Logic Pro X` process and started the installer again, however all process is now gone and it gets stuck at `Installing`:

[image]

How can I reset the installer so it starts from scratch? Maybe I could delete the 1.4GB data that was already downloaded so it starts from the beginning?

A quick find didn't reveal where those files are:

```
$ sudo find / -name "*Logic Pro*"
```

**UPDATE:** directories that I try deleting:

- `/Users/jviotti/Library/Caches/com.apple.logic10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the location of your downloaded content by running the following command:

```
sudo find /private/var/folders -name "com.apple.MusicApps"
```

You can safely delete this entire folder and attempt to re-download.

<sup>If your Logic Pro X is not sandboxed, the content will be located in /Library/Application Support/Logic.</sup>

Comment: There is no such folder, neither on `/Library` nor `~/Library`.

Comment: There is a `/Users/jviotti/Library/Caches/com.apple.logic10` though deleting it made no effect

Comment: @jviotti What do you get if you run `sudo find /private/var/folders -name "com.apple.MusicApps"`?

Comment: There is a `/private/var/folders/xn/l9mck7g562xg99wfj85xhll00000gn/C/com.apple.MusicApps` which weights 1.8GB. Is it safe to delete the whole directory?

Comment: @jviotti Yes, it is safe to delete the directory. It contains the same content as the folder I initially referred to, but I forgot about sandboxing :) Edited answer to include details.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to re-download the files after deleting the temporary cache which is stored somewhere under `/private/var/folders`. This is what I ran to remove the files.

First find out where they are by running:

`sudo find /private/ -name '*com.apple.MusicApps*'`

Then if you see results you can either delete them manually or with find once you are sure you have located what you want.

`sudo find /private/ -name '*com.apple.MusicApps*' -delete`